# Redirect domain.tld/index.php to domain.tld (remove index.php and then 301)

Tags: regex, .htaccess, magento, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a Magento installation and was wondering how can I redirect domain.tld/index.php to domain.tld?

I want to remove index.php and then 301 back to root. I have a lot of old links which is giving me duplicate content and ugly urls etc. Example of old link:

```
domain.tld/index.php?controller=best_sales
```

In the .htaccess, I have the following, and it's not working

```
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Thanks :)

---

Edit:

Thanks both of you for your answers, but I still can't get it to work.
I'm getting 404 - Not Found, when trying to make any changes.

This is my full .htaccess, maybe there are some errors or miss-configurations that doesn't make it work?

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on    
RewriteBase /

// REMOVE HOME REWRITE FROM MAGENTO
RewriteRule ^home/?$ /? [R=301,L,NC]

// ADD WWW TO NONE WWW FOR BOTH HTTPS AND NONE HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

// REDIRECT ALL .HTML FILES AND ALL .HTML/ FILES WITH TRAILING SLASH
RewriteRule ^google[0-9a-f]+.html$ - [L]
RewriteRule (.+)\.html$ /$1/ [L,R=301]
RewriteRule (.+)\.html\/$ /$1/ [L,R=301]

// ADD TRAILING SLASH
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

// TRAILING SLASH CHECK
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [L,R=301]

// CHECK IF REDIRECT POINTS TO A VALID FILE
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

// SEND TO INDEX.PHP FOR CLEAN URLS
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php? /$1 [L,QSA]
#REWRITE EVERYTHING ELSE TO INDEX.PHP    
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep this rule as **your very first rule** below `RewriteEngine On` line to remove `index.php` from your URL:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php$ /$1 [L,R=302,NC,NE]
```

Comment: Thanks anubhava! Getting a 404, please see my answer for further info.

Comment: You .htaccess is not showing my suggested rule. You need to insert my suggested rule just below `RewriteBase /` line.

Comment: Seems to be working fine :) If I want to strip out the querystring, can I add i question mark after the root slash in someway? And if I just need it on the root level, and not in sub directories, is that possible?

Comment: Yes add a question mark in the end like `RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php$ /$1? [L,R=302,NC,NE]` to strip out query string. You can use this rule in root .htaccess also.

Comment: Thanks again. The rule is intend to run only at root, as I am afraid that removing query strings, will break functions and urls in sub directories.

Comment: Yes that's true better not to remove query string in that case.

Comment: So is it possible to change the rule to ONLY change when on root, and not in subcategories?

Comment: Yes sure that can be done: `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s+/index\.php [NC]` to target root only.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that without any rules it already displays your content for `domain.tld/?controller=best_unicorns`. If the url before the query string *ends with 'index.php'*, you want to *redirect* to that url without index.php. In fact, the part between the domain name and the query string only contains 'index.php'.

You'll need to use the `R` (redirect) flag for this:

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ / [R,L]
```

Delete your other attempt. If this rule works, change the flags to `[R=301,L]` to make it permanent. This way both browsers and search engines know to look in just one place.

Comment: Thanks Sumurai8! Getting a 404, please see my answer for further info.

Comment: Make sure this rule is listed as the first rule. If the problem persists, find out what url it is actually trying to load on the server. Find out what url it should load instead. My approach will probably cause an infinite loop because of your last rule, unless you replace that with `DirectoryIndex index.php`. Anubhava's answer should work, even though you should replace it with a permanent redirect when everything works as expected.